# What function in R would give me the number of rows that only have X columns

Tags: r, dataset

I have a dataset that looks like this (the Groceries dataset from the arules CRAN package)

libraries:

```
library(arules);
library(datasets);
data(Groceries);
```

Dataset example:

```
transactions\items   

1           item1      item2      item3
2           item1      item2      item4     item5    item7
3           item1      item2      item4     item5    item6    item7
4           item1      item2      item3     item7    item8
```

I would like to know:

1- what function in R would give me the transactions with only 5 items(columns)?

The expected output is row 2 and 4 since they have only 5 items.

2- what function in R would give me the transactions with at least 5 items(columns)?

The expected output is row 2 and 3 and 4 since they contain at least 5 items

Thank you.
Here is the output of inspect(Groceries[1:3]):

```
   items                
[1] {citrus fruit,       
     semi-finished bread,
     margarine,          
     ready soups}        
[2] {tropical fruit,     
     yogurt,             
     coffee}             
[3] {whole milk}
```

Here is the output of dput(head(Groceries)):

```
new("transactions", data = new("ngCMatrix", i = c(13L, 60L, 69L, 
78L, 14L, 29L, 98L, 24L, 15L, 29L, 38L, 92L, 22L, 24L, 33L, 123L, 
24L, 25L, 29L, 65L, 138L), p = c(0L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 21L
), Dim = c(169L, 6L), Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL), factors = list()), 
    itemInfo = structure(list(labels = c("frankfurter", "sausage", 
    "liver loaf", "ham", "meat", "finished products", "organic sausage", 
    "chicken", "turkey", "pork", "beef", "hamburger meat", "fish", 
    "citrus fruit", "tropical fruit", "pip fruit", "grapes", 
    "berries", "nuts/prunes", "root vegetables", "onions", "herbs", 
    "other vegetables", "packaged fruit/vegetables", "whole milk", 
    "butter", "curd", "dessert", "butter milk", "yogurt", "whipped/sour cream", 
    "beverages", "UHT-milk", "condensed milk", "cream", "soft cheese", 
    "sliced cheese", "hard cheese", "cream cheese ", "processed cheese", 
    "spread cheese", "curd cheese", "specialty cheese", "mayonnaise", 
    "salad dressing", "tidbits", "frozen vegetables", "frozen fruits", 
    "frozen meals", "frozen fish", "frozen chicken", "ice cream", 
    "frozen dessert", "frozen potato products", "domestic eggs", 
    "rolls/buns", "white bread", "brown bread", "pastry", "roll products ", 
    "semi-finished bread", "zwieback", "potato products", "flour", 
    "salt", "rice", "pasta", "vinegar", "oil", "margarine", "specialty fat", 
    "sugar", "artif. sweetener", "honey", "mustard", "ketchup", 
    "spices", "soups", "ready soups", "Instant food products", 
    "sauces", "cereals", "organic products", "baking powder", 
    "preservation products", "pudding powder", "canned vegetables", 
    "canned fruit", "pickled vegetables", "specialty vegetables", 
    "jam", "sweet spreads", "meat spreads", "canned fish", "dog food", 
    "cat food", "pet care", "baby food", "coffee", "instant coffee", 
    "tea", "cocoa drinks", "bottled water", "soda", "misc. beverages", 
    "fruit/vegetable juice", "syrup", "bottled beer", "canned beer", 
    "brandy", "whisky", "liquor", "rum", "liqueur", "liquor (appetizer)", 
    "white wine", "red/blush wine", "prosecco", "sparkling wine", 
    "salty snack", "popcorn", "nut snack", "snack products", 
    "long life bakery product", "waffles", "cake bar", "chewing gum", 
    "chocolate", "cooking chocolate", "specialty chocolate", 
    "specialty bar", "chocolate marshmallow", "candy", "seasonal products", 
    "detergent", "softener", "decalcifier", "dish cleaner", "abrasive cleaner", 
    "cleaner", "toilet cleaner", "bathroom cleaner", "hair spray", 
    "dental care", "male cosmetics", "make up remover", "skin care", 
    "female sanitary products", "baby cosmetics", "soap", "rubbing alcohol", 
    "hygiene articles", "napkins", "dishes", "cookware", "kitchen utensil", 
    "cling film/bags", "kitchen towels", "house keeping products", 
    "candles", "light bulbs", "sound storage medium", "newspapers", 
    "photo/film", "pot plants", "flower soil/fertilizer", "flower (seeds)", 
    "shopping bags", "bags"), level2 = structure(c(44L, 44L, 
    44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 42L, 42L, 41L, 5L, 5L, 23L, 25L, 
    25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 37L, 18L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
    24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 22L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 16L, 
    16L, 16L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 30L, 30L, 3L, 3L, 43L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 31L, 31L, 33L, 9L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 1L, 15L, 
    15L, 52L, 52L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 6L, 6L, 29L, 29L, 
    29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
    32L, 32L, 32L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 45L, 21L, 
    21L, 21L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 4L, 4L, 28L, 20L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
    17L, 17L, 48L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 35L, 35L, 
    35L, 35L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("baby food", 
    "bags", "bakery improver", "bathroom cleaner", "beef", "beer", 
    "bread and backed goods", "candy", "canned fish", "canned fruit/vegetables", 
    "cheese", "chewing gum", "chocolate", "cleaner", "coffee", 
    "condiments", "cosmetics", "dairy produce", "delicatessen", 
    "dental care", "detergent/softener", "eggs", "fish", "frozen foods", 
    "fruit", "games/books/hobby", "garden", "hair care", "hard drinks", 
    "health food", "jam/sweet spreads", "long-life bakery products", 
    "meat spreads", "non-alc. drinks", "non-food house keeping products", 
    "non-food kitchen", "packaged fruit/vegetables", "perfumery", 
    "personal hygiene", "pet food/care", "pork", "poultry", "pudding powder", 
    "sausage", "seasonal products", "shelf-stable dairy", "snacks", 
    "soap", "soups/sauces", "staple foods", "sweetener", "tea/cocoa drinks", 
    "vegetables", "vinegar/oils", "wine"), class = "factor"), 
        level1 = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
        6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
        5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 
        9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
        9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 
        10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
        10L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 
        8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
        7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("canned food", 
        "detergent", "drinks", "fresh products", "fruit and vegetables", 
        "meat and sausage", "non-food", "perfumery", "processed food", 
        "snacks and candies"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -169L), class = "data.frame"), itemsetInfo = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please do not delete your posts with many comments just to put up the *exact same* question again!

Comment: As already suggested, either use apply to count non-NAs entries by row, or reshape the data long and then just count by group! Did you try that?

Comment: @tino_ladino could you please explain further the apply function, I am a total noob in R, I want from the dataset to get the rows(transactions) that have only 5 columns(items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
library(arules)
data(Groceries)

data <- as(Groceries, "data.frame")

library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  filter(str_count(items, ",")==4) -> Groceries5

head(Groceries5)
                                                                   items
1                       {whole milk,butter,yogurt,rice,abrasive cleaner}
2 {other vegetables,UHT-milk,rolls/buns,bottled beer,liquor (appetizer)}
3  {tropical fruit,other vegetables,white bread,bottled water,chocolate}
4   {tropical fruit,cream cheese ,processed cheese,detergent,newspapers}
5          {root vegetables,other vegetables,whole milk,beverages,sugar}
6           {whole milk,yogurt,processed cheese,pickled vegetables,soda}
```